# Append row count and date to filename

Tags: date, wc

Is there a way to append both a row count and a date to a filename? I have a file I am creating in SAP and upon output I would like to run a script to change the filename per my client's specifications. Here's what I have:

```
#!/bin/ksh
## $1 = Folder

F1=TEST_FILE
COUNT=$wc -l < output.txt
DATE=$date "+%Y%m%d"
EXTENSION=_01_01.txt
FILENAME=${F1)_${COUNT)_${DATE}_${EXTENSION}

cd $1

cp output.txt $FILENAME

exit 0
```

Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it, you can try this:

```
#!/bin/ksh -
## $1 = Folder

cd -P -- "$1" || exit

F1="TEST_FILE"
COUNT=$(($(wc -l < output.txt))) || exit
DATE=$(date "+%Y%m%d")
EXTENSION="_01_01.txt"
FILENAME="${F1}_${COUNT}_${DATE}_${EXTENSION}"

cp output.txt "$FILENAME"
```

> Command substitution allows the output of a command to be substituted in place of the command name itself. Command substitution shall occur when the command is enclosed as follows:
>
> ```
>  $(command)
> ```

As @don_crissti told, read more in [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03)

Comment: That worked. I need to figure out why my count doesn't work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JosephPrespare, you need to cd before running wc. See edit for other things to consider.